# cuda thread indexing

Tags: c, cuda

is this right expression for matrix indexing (dim3 threadBlock = (A, B, 1), dim3 blockGrid = (C, D, 1), where A, B, C, D are some numbers) ?

```
int i = (blockIdx.y * gridDim.x + blockIdx.x) * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
int j = (blockIdx.x * gridDim.y + blockIdx.y) * blockDim.y + threadIdx.y;
```

Answer (score 5):

That doesn't look correct to my eyes. The `(i,j)` indices of any thread in a two dimensional CUDA grid are

```
int idx_i = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
int idx_j = blockIdx.y * blockDim.y + threadIdx.y;
```

If you are accessing an array stored in linear memory the equivalent `(i,j)` index is either

```
int mindex_colmajor = idx_i + idx_j * LDA;
```

or

```
int mindex_rowmajor = idx_j + idy_i * LDA;
```

depending on whether the array is stored in [row major or column major order](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row-major_order) with a first dimension in memory (or equivalently pitch) equal to `LDA`. You then access the memory as

```
value = array[mindex]
```

where `mindex` is either the column major or row major index calculated above.

Comment: thanks for reply.
but there is no information about grid. i am confused because on nvidia forum i found examples for two dimensional block and grid like:
UniqueBlockIndex = blockIdx.y * gridDim.x + blockIdx.x;
UniqueThreadIndex =UniqueBlockIndex * blockDim.y * blockDim.x + threadIdx.y * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
but i need two indexes (idx_i and idx_j)

Comment: What do you mean "but there is no information about grid"? The information I have given you is both correct and easily found in the CUDA programming guide, should you care to look for it......

Answer (score 1):

That is one way to index into the matrix from threads, but not the only way. For example, I could change the kernel so that each thread deals with more than one matrix item.

Comment: user1281071: You did not ask for the fastest way in your question :-) In any case, the fastest indexing is not the only factor for speed, it will also depend on what you intend to compute in the kernel.

Comment: ok, sry :) i would like to have system like: one thread = one matrix item but i do not know if the expression which is written above is correct for two dimensional block and grid.